# New off-topic close reason for question that are... off-topic?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons

Lately we've seen a bunch of question about Windows, english usage, general programming questions, and when we should take the dog to a walk... so, I was thinking that instead of writing up a "custom" reason each time... some should be prewritten, no? Any ideas of what this text should say?

Answer (score 13):

Proposed text:

> This question is not about Unix or Linux. Questions about other operating systems can be asked on [Super User](http://superuser.com) and questions about general programming on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com). See the [help page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for a description of what kinds of questions are on topic here.

Answer (score 12):

I actually prefer that people are encouraged to think of a constructive reason for closing (for off-topic) and articulate it prior to clicking the button.

It may only be a small cognitive hurdle, but it does encourage thoughtful votes to close, at least from the first voter, rather than just the cost of a click.

I think this contributes to the overall high quality nature of the content management on the site and I don't think it is worth trading away for a very small gain in perceived convenience.

We aren't at the size yet—from my perspective visiting daily—where the volume of posts would make this a more compelling argument. Until we are, I think we should try and preserve the thoughtful, measured environment that has been cultivated to date.

Comment: You make a good point. Still, some questions are simply plain off topic, what if someone asks about the best way for stringing a guitar? It would be nice to have a ready-made, polite and clear reason. I have often found myself voting to close as off topic and would have liked to include a link to the [help] or [on-topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) pages, explaining the scope of the site. Having that option in the close menu would be a help.

Comment: Don't we already have a boilerplate about it not being within the site's scope? The top option on the second screen (it includes those links).

Comment: Not unless it's a >10k rep feature. The top option on the second screen after choosing off topic for me is what became of too localized: "Questions describing a problem that can't be reproduced and seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed) are off-topic as they are unlikely to help future readers. "

Comment: Nevermind: I only looked on Meta :( It's still *very* early here...

Comment: Ah, perfect, that's the one I'd like to see on the main site.

Comment: So, are we getting a new "Off-topic" reason?

Comment: @Braiam Tag it as a feature request and the site admins can decide based on their experience with other sites and our discussion here.

Comment: @jasonwryan And, over three years later, we still don't have a [status] or even a comment from an admin. (If I recall correctly, terdon wasn't a moderator yet in 2013.)